# Java keyword extraction from wikipedia articles

Tags: java, tomcat, jakarta-ee, hadoop, solr

I have a list of documents and I am indexing those documents based on User's query on Apache SOLR. I want to extract some news articles by using the keywords from the relevant indexed documents and display it along with the indexed documents to the user. Is there any algorithm or procedure by which we can extract the relevant keywords from the documents and use it for extracting the news?

Comment: What do you classify as a "relevant keyword"?

Comment: relevant keyword means the keyword which is relevant to the user based on the user query. If I try this for a query as 'soccer game' then soccer is a relevant keyword for me in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You should research [TF-IDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf) keyword extraction. I did a similar process with this about 2 years ago using the English Wiki and a simple Python Script. You need to answer a few questions though before proceeding with this. You can find  a neat little writeup on using TF-IDF keyword extraction [here](http://www.joyofdata.de/blog/tf-idf-statistic-keyword-extraction/)

- Do you only care about single keywords or will you evaluate phrases as well and up to what length?
- Will you do any natural language processing on incoming data such as tagging and stemming?
- Will you restrict the keywords to certain article types? Certain categories of article can have their own TF-IDF scores so you might want to experiment with what you need.

Comment: I would like to have keywords as well as phrases as they are available in the user query. But those should be relevant keywords which sum up the entire query and not other stopwords or non relevant stuff. And yes..  I will be doing processing on those queries using Apache SOLR.